# Best practice redirect to 'under construction' page after taking down old website

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have been asked to take down a website, and as such have removed the files and placed a new index page with a 'under construction' message while the new site is being created.  Old pages from the site still show up in google, but now resolve 403-Forbidden.

I want these to redirect to the under construction page.  This will likely be in effect for a few weeks, at which point I will want to permanently redirect (301) those pages to cooresponding pages on the new site.

Is there an easy trick (.htaccess) to make this happen for me?  Do I want a 303 redirect?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

---

**EDIT**

well thanks for the answers, I didn't realize until now that this is not an Apache server so htacess will not work.  The code in the answers will definitely come in handy in the future however.  I'm gonna poke around a bit to look for a solution and will ask another question if I'm stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, redirects to index.php;

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
</ifModule>
```

Comment: is the `/$1` segment necessary?  I dont want to redirect to index.php/<something> just index.php

Comment: What if your solution is in a folder such as `temp/index.php` or `under_construction/index.php`. It seems to kill all relative links.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `.htaccess` file, replacing `index.php` by the file it needs to redirect to.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.)+$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: I think this creates an infinite loop, as 'index.php' is matches and rewritten to 'index.php', etc. etc.